# Pygame Display Update Glitch?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I have some code that is kinda funky. Basically, the variable gameStart is in a variable that uses the function, cursorOver, which finds and detects where and if the mouse button is and if it is pressed. I have 3 buttons and I want each button to become larger when the cursor is over the button. The first button implementation works. However, if I try to add another button, the button becomes enlarged, however, the button starts flickering.

```
window.blit(background,(0,0))
window.blit(title,(175,200))
pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(50,400,200,100),0)
pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(300,400,200,100),0)
pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(550,400,200,100),0)
close()

mouseX,mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
mouseClick = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]

gameStartC = cursorOver(50,400,200,100,mouseX,mouseY)
instructionStartC = cursorOver(300,400,200,100,mouseX,mouseY)
objectiveStartC = cursorOver(550,400,200,100,mouseX,mouseY)
nextStartC = cursorOver(580,250,175,100,mouseX,mouseY)

if gameStartC == True:
    while True:
        pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(25,375,250,150),0)
        pygame.display.update()
        break
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(50,400,200,100),0)
    pygame.display.update()
#this is the part where the code becomes glitchy
if instructionStartC == True:
    while True:
        pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(275,375,250,150),0)
        pygame.display.update()
        break
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(300,400,200,100),0)
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image: The image is the menu screen that I want to impliment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because you call `pygame.display.update()` multiple times.

You should create a standard game loop that typically does these three things:

- handle input
- update state
- draw to screen

and then repeats.

In the 'draw to screen'-step, you draw all your sprites/rects/whatever to the screen surface, and then eventually call `pygame.display.update()` once at the end.

Calling `pygame.display.update()` multiple times, not clearing the screen between iterations of the loop and creating multiple unnecessary event loops are common beginner mistakes that lead to those kind of glitches IMHO.

So in your case, the code should probably look more like this:

```
if gameStartC:
    pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(25,375,250,150),0)
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(50,400,200,100),0)

if instructionStartC:
    pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(275,375,250,150),0)
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(window,PURPLE,(300,400,200,100),0)

pygame.display.update()
```

I don't know what you expected the `while`-loops to do, and maybe you should use pygames `Rect` and `Sprite` classes. It will make your life easier.